# Python: Parsing timestamps and calculating time differences in milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime

I have a list of timestamps in "%H:%M:%S" format. For example

```
  09:50:08.650000
  09:50:08.665000
  09:50:08.820000
  09:50:08.877000
  09:50:09.897000
  09:50:09.907000
  09:50:09.953000
  09:50:10.662000
  09:50:10.662000
```

I need to compute efficiently in python the time difference in milliseconds between each line.

Comment: The format is `'%H:%M:%S.%f'`.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I have a timedelta representation now. How do I compute the difference in milliseconds?

Comment: `int(diff.seconds * 1000. + diff.microseconds / 1000.)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%H:%M:%S.%f` is the format string to be used when parsing the times. See http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
import datetime

times = """
09:50:08.650000
09:50:08.665000
09:50:08.820000
09:50:08.877000
09:50:09.897000
09:50:09.907000
09:50:09.953000
09:50:10.662000
09:50:10.662000
""".split()

# parse all times
times = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for x in times]
for i in range(len(times) - 1):
    # compute timedelta between current and next time in the list
    print times[i + 1] - times[i]
```

The result:

```
0:00:00.015000
0:00:00.155000
0:00:00.057000
0:00:01.020000
0:00:00.010000
0:00:00.046000
0:00:00.709000
0:00:00
```

To output the difference in milliseconds:

```
delta = times[i + 1] - times[i]
print ((delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + delta.seconds) * 1000 + delta.microseconds / 1000)
```

Note that [timedelta](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) only stores days, seconds and microseconds internally. Other units are converted.

Comment: For the conversion in milliseconds, see comment from eurmiro in question comments.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've added the conversion and included days (if that ever is needed).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `datetime.strptime()` function? It will read in the datetime as a string and convert it into a datetime object.

You can then use `datetime.timedelta()` to compute the difference in milliseconds.

Documentation here: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: I tried but using datetime.strptime but using "%H:%M:%S" as format gives a ValueError because of the milliseconds.

Comment: What was the issue you were having? You should note that the float you are using in the string does present a problem for `strptime()` as %S expects an integer

Comment: See @squidy's answer he handles the "float" properly using "%S.%f" as the time format. I overlooked the fact that technically you are not looking at a float in the string and can just use the "." as a delimiter.